# Data not being written to OrientDB

Tags: etl, orientdb

I have a single column csv file with the column name Links in the first row and then some links in each row, following is my etl file:

```
    {
  "source": { "file": { "path": "fb22.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {
      "columns":["Links:string"]
  } },
  "transformers": [
    { "vertex": { "class": "Links" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:/orientdb/databases/fblinks1",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "Links", "extends": "V"}
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have a database with no vertexes created, when I run oetl fblinks.json file I get the following in the console:

```
E:\orientdb-server\bin>oetl fblinks.json
OrientDB etl v.2.2.29 (build 9914189f972103907c24377a1567897e68642920) https://www.orientdb.com
[file] INFO Load from file fb22.csv
[csv] INFO column types: {Links=STRING}
[file] INFO Reading from file fb22.csv with encoding UTF-8
[orientdb] INFO committing
E:\orientdb-server\bin>
```

But no data is written to the database. Please advise what am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reconfigure the path  to the csv using a full path? So, from fb22.csv to /home/myusername/work/data/fb22.csv